# backbone.js: add an element to a collection without re-rendering all the collection

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I have a view that render itself from a Collection:

```
render: function() {

    $(this.el).html(JST['templates/menu']({collection: this.collection }));
    $('#nav').html(this.el);     
}
```

In the view initializer, i bind the add event of the collection on the render function of the view:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    var self = this;
    this.collection.bind("add", function(event){
        self.render();
    });
}
```

elsewhere in the application, I add an item to the collection.

```
bookSubscription_collection.add(model);
```

The problem with that code is, if I add a new item to the collection, then all the items in the collection are re-rendered.

Is there a way to add a new item to a collection without re-render all the other items, but just render the new item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of binding the collection's add event to the render function, bind it to some other function that accepts the model that was added, and modifies the DOM with data from the model that was added.

Answer (score 4):

This a simplified version of how I'm doing it. `reset` adds all the models to the UI and `add` adds a single model to the UI. `addAll` basically has a loop that calls `addOne` for each model. It could probably be optimized better but it works well enough.

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addOne', 'addAll');

    leads.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
    leads.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.addAll();
    return this;
  },
  addOne: function(model) {
    // add the model to HTML
  },
  addAll: function(options) {
    leads.each(this.addOne);
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Any improvement on this where the actual HTML inject is called once if adding ie. 10 models?

Answer (score 0):

abraham wrote a good example. Ive been also using it like this

```
initialize: ->    
  self = @
  @model.bind "add", (task) ->
    $(self.el).append new app.TaskIndexItemView(model: task).render().el
```

but i think the addOne is better solution

Comment: why `self = @`? it's the same without it and you should use fat arrow => for binding scope then instead of doing `$(self.el)` you can do `$(@el)` or if you are using backbone 0.9+ you should use `@$el` which uses cached jQuery wrapped instance of `this.el`